# Make urlencode a synonym of url-encoding

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The [urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlencode) description reads

> This is about encoding text in/for a URL. Some characters are not valid for URLs. For instance ' or \ and more.

The [url-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-encoding) description reads

> URL Encoding, also known as Percent-encoding, is a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) set, which includes both Uniform Resource Locator (URL) and Uniform Resource Name (URN).
>
> As such, it is also used in the preparation of data of the application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type, as is often used in the submission of HTML form data in HTTP requests.

The descriptions indicate that they mean the same thing, and at a glance, there doesn't seem to be any difference in how they're used in practice. The former should probably be made a synonym of the latter.

I'd make the suggestion myself, but am not authorized to as I haven't answered any questions in either tag.

Comment: [tag:urlencode] is normally a specific function, whereas [tag:url-encoding] is a concept.

Comment: @Ben: So, for tagging on SO they have the same meaning, right?

Comment: It depends on whether you're asking about a problem with the function `urlencode` or a more generic question about encoding URLs @Deduplicator. To conflate the two would be to insinuate that SO is for nothing more than debugging, which I strongly disagree with.

Comment: @Ben it's used for `urlencode` functions from various different languages, though (as well as for questions that are about URL encoding but not about any function called `urlencode`). Since tags should stand alone, treating it as referring to different specific function depending upon the language tag would make it a meta tag, so that's not an acceptable usage. I figure this means either we can treat it as a synonym of url-encoding, as I've suggested here, or create new tags for each possible language's urlencode function it's ever been used for and retag all 1000 questions manually.

Comment: @Ben ... and I think the synonym approach is the better of the two, because really, who's going to add some particular language's urlencode function to their list of favorite tags? In any case, we're definitely not losing any *existing* useful information by making the two tags synonyms.

Comment: These tags should be merged. As it stands, they're used interchangeably. There's no real distinction between the two tags in practice.

Comment: (I did not find this discussion before creating my own): [The tags \[percent-encoding\], \[uriencoding\], \[urlencode\], and \[url-encoding\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290461/1591669)

Comment: @unor I've closed mine as a dupe, since yours covers more tags and is therefore better. (Apparently, I can close my own questions as dupes unilaterally now!)