# The tags [percent-encoding], [uriencoding], [urlencode], and [url-encoding]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have four tags that seem to be about the same concept:

- [urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlencode) (1181)

  > This is about encoding text in/for a URL. Some characters are not valid for URLs. For instance ' or \ and more.
- [url-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-encoding) (629)

  > URL Encoding is a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under certain circumstances.
- [percent-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent-encoding) (60)

  > Percent-encoding (aka URL encoding) is the way that non-alphabet characters are encoded in URLs and URIs (e.g. spaces turn into %20).
- [uriencoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uriencoding) (22)

  (No tag excerpt/wiki.)

What to do?

I think we should only have one tag: [percent-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent-encoding)

- [url-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-encoding) becomes a synonym of [percent-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent-encoding)
- [urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlencode) and [uriencoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uriencoding) get merged/retagged with [percent-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent-encoding)

While [url-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-encoding) could as well become the master tag, I think [percent-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent-encoding) is the better choice because we would not have to decide if to use "uri" or "url", and as the tag name doesn’t contain one of these terms, users are less likely to confuse it with punycode (as the domain is also part of the URI and it’s also an encoding, so users *might* use "url-encoding" for questions about punycode). But I’m fine with [url-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-encoding), too.

[urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlencode) sounds like a function name of a programming language instead of the name of the concept, but as it was not defined to be for such a specific function, we can’t retroactively define it like that because more than 1000 questions used it already without this meaning.

[uriencoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uriencoding) misses a hyphen.

Comment: What would you suggest? You've added two tags that include the word "request", but you've not *requested* anything.

Comment: There is also a **[encodeuricomponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encodeuricomponent)**

Comment: @ShaunakD: But that is specifically for the JavaScript function, so I guess it’s fine as it is.

Comment: @KenWhite: Right, I added my suggestion.

Comment: Just found that [tag:urlencode] and [tag:url-encoding] also get discussed here: [Make urlencode a synonym of url-encoding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253636/1591669)

Comment: One more vote for [tag:url-encoding] is needed..